# Scaffolding Db Context and automatically remove the OnConfiguring method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

For our ASP.NET Core project we scaffold the existing database using the  Scaffold-DbContext in the Package Manger console.

Every time we do the scaffolding, a context class is generated together with all the entities and it contains the OnConfiguring(..) method which calls optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(..) to  configure the context to connect to the SQL server database.

We have our connection string defined in the appsettings.json file and don't want to use the OnConfiguring(..) method, so the question is, if there is a way to automatically remove the OnConfiguring(..) method, so that we don't have to do that manually everytime we run the scaffolding.

Answer (score 23):

FYI there is a `-NoOnConfiguring` option coming in EF Core 5.0

`-NoOnConfiguring Don't generate DbContext.OnConfiguring. Added in EF Core 5.0.`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: Wow, I am very surprised by this.  If you look at there github they were very adamant to not introduce such a feature, despite all the requests.  It looks like Microsoft is finally starting to listen to what people want.

Answer (score 7):

The option you are searching for is: **--no-onconfiguring**

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
    "server=.\SqlExpress;database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True" 
     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
     --no-onconfiguring
```

Comment: This is no longer working in EFCore 7. I'm trying to discover how to do this now as the route involving Name= leads to a different error around using Iconfiguration which doesn't apply to my project.

Answer (score -4):

First of all. I would recommend you using dotnet core migration cli to scaffold your database. Detail of command can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet).

Using dotnet core migration cli you only need to define your config in your applicationdbcontext class like this

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
        relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithOne().HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(r => r.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.RoleId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(r => r.Users).WithOne().HasForeignKey(r => r.RoleId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.EnableAutoHistory(null);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Medias)
        .WithOne(m => m.Post)
        .HasForeignKey<Media>(p => p.PostId);
}
```

And you only need to defined your connection in startup.cs file like this

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
b => b.MigrationsAssembly("AwesomeCMSCore")).UseOpenIddict());
```

Hope I make it clear for you. Please let me know if you have any problem

Full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs) and [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/Extension/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L171-L179)